# Determine if input word can be created from a list of letters

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I am looking for a more elegant way to validate in an input word can be created from a list of letters.

```py
# Necessary variables (change as needed to test your code).
user_word = 'BANANA'
letters = ['N', 'B', 'N', 'A', 'A', 'P', 'M', 'S', 'A']



# This function checks whether a word entered by the user contains appropriate letters.
# It receives the letters and the word as parameter values, and returns True or False.
def validate_word(word, letters):
    from collections import Counter
    Count = Counter(letters)
    for letters in word:
        if not Count[letters]:
            return False
        Count[letters] -= 1
    return True


# Print the return value of the function to test it.
print(validate_word(user_word, letters))
```

As commented the function needs to return `True` if all the letters in the word are in the list, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Imports

In general, imports should be listed at the top of the script, not inside function definitions.  So instead of this:

```
def validate_word(words, letters):
    from collections import Counter
    ...
```

Write:

```
from collections import Counter

def validate_word(words, letters):
    ...
```

### Variable names

In Python, variable names should be `snake_case`.  Words beginning with upper case letters are reserved from classes, like `Counter`, so `Count` should be called `count`.

### Test Code

`user_word` and `letters` are declared far from the code that uses them.  They should be declared near where they are used, so at the bottom of the script, and ideally inside a `__name__ == '__main__'` guard:

```
from collections import Counter

def validate_word(word, letters):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_word = 'BANANA'
    letters = ['N', 'B', 'N', 'A', 'A', 'P', 'M', 'S', 'A']
    print(validate_word(user_word, letters))
```

### A String is a List of Characters

The `Counter` class accepts an iterable for its construction argument, such as the list of letters you want to count.  But a string is also an iterable list of characters, so instead of a list, you could simply pass in a string, and it would work just as well:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_word = 'BANANA'
    letters = 'NBNAAPMSA'
    print(validate_word(user_word, letters))
```

### Counters

You are counting up the counts of letters you are allowed to use.  Why not count up the count of letters in the `user_word`?

```
>>> Counter('NBNAAPMSA')
Counter({'A': 3, 'N': 2, 'B': 1, 'P': 1, 'M': 1, 'S': 1})
>>> Counter('BANANA')
Counter({'A': 3, 'N': 2, 'B': 1})
```

Then instead of looping over the letters of the user word, and subtracting 1 from the letter count, you could compare the letter counts directly.

Or ... you could subtract one from the other ...

```
>>> counts = Counter('NBNAAPMSA')
>>> counts.subtract('BANANA')
>>> counts
Counter({'P': 1, 'M': 1, 'S': 1, 'N': 0, 'B': 0, 'A': 0})
>>>
```

As long as all values in the counter are non-negative, the word is valid.

```
>>> all(count >= 0 for count in counts.values())
True
```

From this, a simpler function can be created.  Left to student.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very short way to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
def validate_word(word: str, letters: list) -> bool:
    """
    Determines if the `word` can be made out of `letters`
    """
    matched_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        for index, value in enumerate(letters):
            if value == letter:
                matched_word += value
                del letters[index]
                break
    return word == matched_word
```

What this does it loop through `word` and `letters`. It then matches up each `letter` in `word` and `letters`, and if they match, it adds it to the matched_word. It then returns if they are equal or not.

The `break` is used to exit out of the inner loop, so multiple letters are not added if they match.

Comment: Yuk.  Ditch the inner loop, use `letters.remove(letter)`, and catch the `ValueError` exception and return `False` if the letter wasn't present.  Return `True` if you were able to `list.remove(letter)` for all of the letters in `word`.  No need for `matched_word`.